# Returning List<ModelObject> to Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I realize this question has been asked a few times, and I went through most of them and ended up trying to do it in two different ways but I can't figure out a couple of issues I'm dealing with.

I have a list of SystemSettings on a table on my DB. So I want to display these settings on a view, allowing the user to edit them as they want. I am attempting to avoid having to do it in a non-dynamic way, because the system is pretty much still in flux so we can end up adding/removing/editing some of them, and I think doing it this way should save some future dev work.

This is the ViewModel I am using:

```
public class SystemSettingsViewModel
{
    public IList<SystemSetting> SystemSettings { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And my object SystemSetting looks like:

```
public class SystemSetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //I don't really use this in the view, but I need it for something else
    public short PendingOperationId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I've tried a couple of different approaches on my view, first one I tried was using indexes with a for loop:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SystemSettings"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.SystemSettings.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=@string.Concat("setting_Value", Model.SystemSettings[i].Key) title=@Model.SystemSettings[i].Description>@Model.SystemSettings[i].DisplayName</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control", id = string.Concat("setting_Value", Model.SystemSettings[i].Key) })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].Value)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].Key)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SystemSettings[i].DisplayName)
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

I also tried using EditorTemplates, leaving the view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SystemSettings"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SystemSettings)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

And the EditorTemplate view like this (SystemSetting.cshtml)

```
@model MyModel.SystemSetting
<div class="form-group">
    <label for=@string.Concat("setting_Value", Model.Key) title=@Model.Description>@Model.DisplayName</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "form-control", id = string.Concat("setting_Value", Model.Key) })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Value)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Key)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DisplayName)
</div>
```

My issues are:

Both approaches display the view like I want, well, except for the tooltip in the label which produces something weird like this:

```
<label for="setting_ValueDefaultTimeoutInMilliseconds" title="Default" timeout="" in="" milliseconds.="">Default timeout (ms)</label>
```

And when I get the object back on my controller, the members of my ViewModel are null.

The signature of my controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(SystemSettingsViewModel systemSettings)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been away from MVC for a bit but have you tried using your view model for the @model part, instead of the SystemSetting class?

Comment: The issue with the label is that you have not quoted the value of the attribute  - `title="@Model.Description"`. I'll dupe it for the other (just change the parameter to `SystemSettingsViewModel model`)